How do I to correct the α in the power analysis？
The reviewer asked us to use a corrected α when calculating the sample size with G*Power.
The literature I found suggests that the Bonferroni adjustment = α/n (Armitage, Peter; Colton, Theodore, 2005).
Here, n refers to the number of tests. I'm not entirely sure what this means.
For example, I am using a 2 (Gender: Male vs. Female) × 3 (Scores: English vs. Math vs. History) repeated measures ANOVA, with Gender as the between-subjects variable and Scores as the within-subjects variable.
The comparisons include 1) the main effect of Gender (differences in scores between males and females), 2) the main effect of Scores (differences in scores among the three subjects), and 3) the interaction effect of Gender * Scores.
Could you please advise on what value n should be when calculating the sample size? (Bonferroni adjustment = α/n)
Reference: Armitage, Peter; Colton, Theodore (2005). Encyclopedia of Biostatistics || Bonferroni Inequalities and Intervals. , 10.1002/0470011815(), –. doi:10.1002/0470011815.b2a15014

Welcome to Cross Validated! From what you describe, it seems that you have 5 coefficients (beyond the Intercept) for which you are reporting p-values: 1 for Gender, 2 for Scores, and 2 for their interaction. That would seem to be 5 tests. Is that correct? It would be best if you could clarify that by editing your question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. In the meantime, look at this answer for a method that's preferable to the Bonferroni adjustment.

Why use Bonferroni? This seems one of these relics from the past, before computers existed. Why not use Sidak, or even better, Holm-Sidak, which will have higher power? What is the basis for saying that Bonferroni is the "best" suggestion? It is the easiest to compute, yes, but the most conservative (aka lowest power).

Thank you very much for your answer which is very helpful to me！But I still have some questions. I want to know why their interaction is 2 tests?@EdM

Because I don't know much about statistics/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~, my usual method is to use Bonfreni, I can choose directly from the software.@jginestet

The correct number n of tests to use in multiple-comparison correction is the number of separate comparisons that you are making (or planning to do). So the answer depends on what comparisons you have done (or plan to do).
There are several possibilities in a 2-way 2X3 ANOVA. One extreme is if you only report the overall ANOVA test. Then there is only n = 1 p-value and no need for correction. At another extreme, you might want to do 2-way comparisons among all the 6 combinations of Gender and Scores. There are 15 such 2-way comparisons, for n = 15.
In between those extremes, you might want to correct p-values for the 5 regression coefficients, beyond the Intercept, that are implicit in that ANOVA when you think of it as a multiple regression with interactions. As the Intercept is the estimated outcome when both Gender and Scores are at their reference levels, that will be n = 5: one coefficient for the second level of Gender (evaluated at the reference level of Scores), two coefficients for Scores (evaluated at the reference level of Gender, for each of the two levels beyond the reference level of Scores), and two interaction coefficients (one for each combination of Gender and Scores that doesn't involve either reference level).
Whichever value of n is appropriate for your study, don't use the simple Bonferroni method. It has a high risk of throwing out potentially true differences. For example, in the n = 15 case, any original p-value would need to be less than 0.0033 to be deemed "significant" after Bonferroni correction. The Holm modification is similarly stringent for the lowest p-value but is less stringent for higher p-values. Tukey's HSD can often be appropriate for all pairwise comparisons.
A final caution
I'm a bit worried by the first sentence of the question:

The reviewer asked us to use a corrected $\alpha$ when calculating the sample size with G*Power.

Power-calculation tools like G*Power are for study design. If the reviewer is evaluating your prospective study design, then that's OK. If this is a reviewer of a study you've already completed, however, then it's not clear why you would be using G*Power at this stage of the study at all. See this page for reasons why "post-hoc power" tests don't make sense.
